# Flutter : DropDown menue dont work with dynamic values

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I created dropddown list as widget with using provider to change values but give me an error, the widget is like this :

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: ApiService().getTeachersLectures(username, token),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var lectures = snapshot.data;
          return Consumer<LecturesProvider>(
              builder: (context, lectureProvider, child) {
            return DropdownButton(
                 value: lectureProvider.index,
                 onChanged: (val) {
                 lectureProvider.changeIndex(val);
                },
                items: lectures.map<DropdownMenuItem>((e) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: e.lecture, child: Text('${e.lecture}'));
            }).toList());
          });
        } else {
          return const Text('not ok');
        }
      },
    )
```

and the provider is simple like this :

```
class LecturesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var index = 0;
  void changeIndex(val) {
    index = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

it is gime this error :

> type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>' is not a subtype of type'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'

Answer (score 0):

The error have been caused because you `List<DropdownMenuItem>` isn't null safety.
If you are sure that this list will never be null just add a null check `!`.

Comment: thanks but I found the mistake, just put the type of DropDownButton